# ReactJs: How to replace html and string template with a component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to manage the content of the page from a **content editor** where I am getting page content from the API.

Check this screenshot.
[image]

I used two different react modules for this `react-html-parser` and `react-string-replace` but it is still not working.

Here is my code.

```
let pageData = '';

pageData = ReactHtmlParser(page.content);

// replacing contact us form with a contact us form component
pageData = reactStringReplace(pageData, '{CONTACT_US_FORM}', (match, i) => (
    <ContactUsForm />
));

return <div>{pageData}</div>;
```

`react-html-parser` -> It is used to parse HTML tags which are in string format into **tree of elements**.

`react-string-replace` -> It is used to replace a string into react a **component**.

**Note:** If I use `react-html-parser` or `react-string-replace` individually then it works fine but it does not work together.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check the `react-string-replace` documentation to see if you are using the API correctly. What does `ReactHtmlParser()` return? Is it a tree of elements? Does `react-string-replace` work on a tree of elements? What is `{pageData}` at the end of your code snippet supposed to do? Is this inside a React component?

Comment: Hi @Martin, I updated the question. ReactHtmlParser returns `tree of elements` and `react-string-replace` does not work with it. Either I need a different module that supports this or needs to do some modifications in the same code.

Comment: What does `page.content` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the expected structure of `page.content`. If it contains HTML you are right in using `react-html-parser`, which has a replace option.

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
const macro = '{CONTACT_US_FORM}';
const replaceContactUsForm = (domhandlerNode) => {
  if (domhandlerNode.type === 'text' && domhandlerNode.data.includes(macro))
    return <ContactUsForm />;
};
// ...
const elements = parse(page.content, { replace: replaceContactUsForm });
return <div>{elements}</div>;
```

Additionally, If the string `{CONTACT_US_FORM}` is embedded in text you could use `react-string-replace` to keep the rest of the text intact:

```
const replaceContactUsForm = (domhandlerNode) => {
  if (domhandlerNode.type === 'text' && domhandlerNode.data.includes(macro))
    return <>{reactStringReplace(domhandlerNode.data, macro, () => (<ContactUsForm />))}</>;
};
```

If `page.content` does not contain HTML you do not need react-html-parser. But judging from your screenshot some markup is probably contained.